# Rule based Classification based on a dictionary

Tags: python, text-classification, topic-modeling

Apologies in advance if this has already been questioned/answered, but I couldn't find any answer close to my problem. I am also somewhat new to Python, so sorry for any wrong formatting or wording.  I am struggling with a task to label/classify a list of documents based on a list of dictionary.
The list of dictionary looks like this:

```
| Category | Keywords       |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Reg      | A, B, C        |
| Gov      | D,E,F,G        |


Document1 = [Sentences1, Sentences 2,...]
Document2 = [Sentences3, Sentences 4,...]
```

I would like to label Documents per Category if keywords belong to this category appear in the document. I have searched through stackoverflow and github but have not found similar problem.

Comment: When you said "dictionary" I expected something in `{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to ask this:

- For a collection of documents, each with multiple sentences, mark each document as belonging to one or more categories if, for any of the given categories, one or more sentences in the document contains at least one keyword from the category.

Here is a way to do that:

```py
categories = {'Reg':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Gov':['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']}
Document1 = ['A quick brown fox.', 'He got a B in calculus.']
Document2 = ['My next job will be in the C suite.', 'You can get there on the D train.']
docs = {'Doc1':Document1, 'Doc2':Document2}
docsByCategory = {}
for doc, sentences in docs.items():
    cats = set()
    for sentence in sentences:
        words = sentence.split()
        for category, keywords in categories.items():
            if any(keyword in words for keyword in keywords):
                cats.add(category)
    docsByCategory[doc] = list(cats)
print(docsByCategory)
```

Output:

```
{'Doc1': ['Reg'], 'Doc2': ['Gov', 'Reg']}
```

Explanation:

- Iterate over the document names and contents using `docs.items()`
- Iterate over the list of sentences the make up each document's contents
- Split each sentence into words
- Iterate over the category names and keywords using `categories.items()`
- Use `any()` with a comprehension (loop) over keywords to see if any of them are found in the sentence's words, in which case add the category name to the variable `cats` which is a `set`, so that multiple calls to `add()` for the same category will result in only a single entry in `cats` for that category
- Convert `cats` to a list and add it to the result dictionary `docsByCategory` for the current document name.

An alternative solution is this:

```
categories = {'Reg':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Gov':['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']}
Document1 = ['A quick brown fox.', 'He got a B in calculus.']
Document2 = ['My next job will be in the C suite.', 'You can get there on the D train.']
docs = {'Doc1':Document1, 'Doc2':Document2}
docsByCategory = {}
for doc, sentences in docs.items():
    sentenceWordSets = [set(sentence.split()) for sentence in sentences]
    cats = set()
    for category, keywords in categories.items():
        keywordSet = set(keywords)
        if any(wordSet & keywordSet for wordSet in sentenceWordSets):
            cats.add(category)
    docsByCategory[doc] = list(cats)
print(docsByCategory)
```